# I need to monitor JVM Metaspace usage

Tags: java

I need to monitor  JVM Metaspace usage. Can you help me please with the following things?

How can I find the metaspace size used ?

Using the following commands I found the maxmetaspace and the min metaspace :

```
jmap -heap `ps -ef | grep java | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'` | grep -i Metaspace
```

> MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
>      MaxMetaspaceSize         = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)

but how can I find what is the value of memory used right now ?

Comment: not so sure. But, I think you can get it by setting flag `-verbose:gc` when you running the java command.

Comment: this way ? jmap -heap `ps -ef | grep java | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'` -verbose:gc    is not working ... Attaching to core -verbose:gc from executable 5270, please wait...
Error attaching to core file: cannot open binary file

Comment: What do you mean verbose:gc is not working? I would fix that first

Comment: can you tell the command that i have to run on my server ? the pid for java is 5270

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `MemoryPoolMXBean`.

```
List<MemoryPoolMXBean> memPool = ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans();
for (MemoryPoolMXBean p : memPool)
{
    if ("Metaspace".equals(p.getName()) 
    {
       ... here you have the memory pool mx bean with information about he metaspace
    }
}
```

Comment: and how can i do that in linux command  ? what i want is to find a linux command who will return the the value of metaspace used right now

Answer (score 3):

I use 
`jstat -gcutil <pid> | awk '{print($5)}'`
that prints the Metaspace utilization as a percentage of the space's current capacity.

there are further options for jstat, explained here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstat.html

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 11, the *jcmd* utility comes with a new command for displaying detailed metaspace information.

```
jcmd <PID> VM.metaspace
```

You can find an in-depth explanation in [this post](https://stuefe.de/posts/metaspace/analyze-metaspace-with-jcmd/) by Thomas Stuefe.

Alternatively, you can also use the JDK Flight Recorder (JFR) for metaspace monitoring, see the "Garbage Collections" view in JMC, and/or "Metaspace Summary" events in the event browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JDK 16, you can write a simple program to monitor your application using the new [Remote streaming API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/jdk.management.jfr/jdk/management/jfr/RemoteRecordingStream.html). First start JMX on the host you want to monitor

```
$ jcmd <pid> ManagementAgent.start jmxremote.port=7091
             jmxremote.authenticate=false jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Then use the following program, which will print all metaspace events to standard out.

```
$ java MetaspaceMonitor.java localhost 7091
```

Source code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;
import jdk.management.jfr.RemoteRecordingStream;

public class MetaspaceMonitor {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        String host = args[0];
        Strin port = args[1];
        String url = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + host + ":" + port + "/jmxrmi";
        JMXServiceURL u = new JMXServiceURL(url);
        JMXConnector c = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(u);
        MBeanServerConnection connection = c.getMBeanServerConnection();
        try (var s = new RemoteRecordingStream(connection)) {
            s.enable("jdk.MetaspaceSummary");
            s.enable("jdk.MetaspaceGCThreshold");
            s.enable("jdk.MetaspaceAllocationFailure").withStackTrace();
            s.enable("jdk.MetaspaceOOM").withStackTrace();
            s.onEvent("jdk.MetaspaceSummary", System.out::println);
            s.onEvent("jdk.MetaspaceGCThreshold", System.out::println);
            s.onEvent("jdk.MetaspaceAllocationFailure", System.out::println);
            s.onEvent("jdk.MetaspaceOOM", System.out::println);
            s.start();
        }
    }
}
```